# C - Doubly linked list (isEmpty)

Tags: c, list

I have doubly linked list and Ive made a function to check whether the list is empty or not.

Function code:

```
int isEmpty(list *l)
{
    if(l->head== NULL && l->tail== NULL)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

List

```
typedef struct list
{
    struct element *head;
    struct element *tail;
}list1;
```

and Im trying to use this function but there is nothing when i open console

```
case 11:
            printf("List is : %d\n", isEmpty(&list1));
            break;
```

Comment: What is the switch for `case 11:`?

Comment: switch(w)
  {
   
 case 11:
            printf("List is : %d\n", isEmpty(&list1));
            break;
}

Comment: Does the code compile? Do you get a runtime error? Or the program runs but doesn't do what you want?

Comment: Have you put a break point on the switch to check that `w` is 11?

Comment: It compiles, no error. Program runs but when i write 11 (11 in switch)  program doesnt write anyhing

Comment: I use scanf("%d", &w); to get w ; I have cases from 1 to 10 and they work, but this 11 doesnt

Comment: Maybe something happens and the execution doesn't go into the `case 11`.  Try putting a `printf("test\n");` inside `case 11` and see what happens

Comment: I put it in case 11 and it doesnt work. no result

Comment: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Well then it seems the problem probably isn't in your list code. That, or somehow you're invoking undefined behavior. Either way I don't think I can help you further, unless you post more of your code.

Comment: Not an answer but you can replace isEmpty with `return (l->head == NULL && l->tail == NULL)`

Answer (score 1):

`list1` is a type so:  `printf("List is : %d\n", isEmpty(&list1));`
is meaningless,

Try:

```
list1 l1;
.
.
.
case 11:
    printf("List is : %d\n", isEmpty(&l1));
    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

It was working but this messsage was disappearing after some milliseconds. I added `system("pause");` and its working now.

Answer (score 0):

You passing wrong parameter to the function. you should pass paramater to isEmpty() such as isEmpty(struct list* l) or isEmpty(list1* l)

```
     int isEmpty(struct list *l)          
     {
       if(l->head== NULL && l->tail== NULL)
           return 1;
       else
           return 0;
     }
```

call the function as

```
         isEmpty(list1)
```

it gives correct result.